# Access 2016 keeps prompting for value when I used vba to insert record

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am a newbie in Access. I have 2 tables: AllCandidates (ID, LastName,FirstName) and CandicateSteps (ID, Step, DateReceived, Result)
My script is to read from excel file, for a pair of LastName, FirstName .  If not exist, then insert LastName, FirstName to the first table, and Step, DateReceived, Result to the second table.
When running, Access keeps prompting me for every single field value, and use that value to put in the table instead of the value I Passed in from Excel.  Could someone please shed light on what I did wrong?  Thanks a lot.

```
Public Sub LoadExcelToAccess(xlPath As String)

    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWrk As Object
    Dim xlSheet As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sql, sql2 As String

    Set xlApp = VBA.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlWrk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(xlPath)
    Set xlSheet = xlWrk.Sheets("Sheet1")

    For i = 2 To 4
        Dim rID
        'check if the person is already in the DB
        Set rID = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select ID from AllCandidates where LastName='" & xlSheet.cells(i, 1) & "' and FirstName = '" & xlSheet.cells(i, 2) & "'")
        If rID.EOF Then
            'person is not in DB, insert it into the AllCandidates db
            MsgBox "ID Not found"
            sql = "Insert Into [AllCandidates] (LastName, FirstName) VALUES (" & xlSheet.cells(i, 1).Value & "," & xlSheet.cells(i, 2).Value & ")"
            DoCmd.RunSQL sql
        End If
        rID.Close

        'now that the person is surely there, insert the steps status into the CandiateSteps table
        Set rID = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select ID from AllCandidates where LastName='" & xlSheet.cells(i, 1) & "' and FirstName = '" & xlSheet.cells(i, 2) & "'")
        'get the last ID that were inserted in the AllCandidates table
        Dim fld As Field
        Set fld = rID.Fields(0)
        MsgBox "item in row ID = " & fld
        sql2 = "Insert into [CandidateSteps] (ID, Step, DateReceived, Result) VALUES (" & fld & ", " & xlSheet.cells(i, 3).Value & ", " & xlSheet.cells(i, 4).Value & ", " & xlSheet.cells(i, 5).Value & ")"
        DoCmd.RunSQL sql2
        rID.Close
    Next i

    'make sure to dispose of objects
    xlWrk.Close
    xlApp.Quit
    Set rID = Nothing
    Set fld = Nothing
    Set xlSheet = Nothing
    Set xlWrk = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You're trying to insert text values without quotes

Comment: thank you so much Tim!!!!  it fixed it!  Silly me!

Answer (score 2):

As @TimWilliams mentions, you are passing string literals (*LastName* and *FirstName*) without quotes for that one problem query which interestingly you do include quotes for all other queries using *LastName* and *FirstName*.

But rather than just wrapping quotes and resolving your problem, consider MS Access' [querydef parameterization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194892.aspx) which do not require *any* quotes or string concatenation. Below are examples of a recordset call (`SELECT` statements) and action query (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` statements) using parameters. Please integrate into your code.

**Parameterized Querydef Recordset**

```
Dim qdef As Querydef 
...

' PREPARED STATEMENT WITH DEFINED PLACEHOLDERS
sql = "PARAMETERS LastNameParam TEXT(255), FirstNameParam TEXT(255);" _ 
       & " SELECT ID from AllCandidates WHERE LastName=[LastNameParam] and FirstName=[FirstNameParam]"

' ASSIGN TO TEMP QUERY OBJECT (ABOVE CAN BE A SAVED QUERY)
Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", sql)

' BIND PARAMS
qdef!LastNameParam = xlSheet.cells(i, 1)   
qdef!FirstNameParam = xlSheet.cells(i, 2)  

' OPEN QUERY'S RECORDSET
Set rID = qdef.OpenRecordset()
...
rID.Close: qdf.Close
Set qdf = Nothing
```

**Parameterized Querydef Action Query** *(Replaces DoCmd.RunSQL)*

```
' PREPARED STATEMENT WITH DEFINED PLACEHOLDERS
sql = "PARAMETERS LastNameParam TEXT(255), FirstNameParam TEXT(255);" _
        & " INSERT INTO [AllCandidates] (LastName, FirstName) VALUES ([LastNameParam], [FirstNameParam])"

' ASSIGN TO TEMP QUERY OBJECT
Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", sql)

' BIND PARAMS
qdef!LastNameParam = xlSheet.cells(i, 1)   
qdef!FirstNameParam = xlSheet.cells(i, 2)  

' EXECUTE ACTION
qdef.Execute dbFailOnError

qdf.Close
Set qdf = Nothing
```

And by the way, since you are a beginner, parameterization is an industry best practice in *any* relational database (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, DB2, SQLite) running SQL queries via application layer coding. Recall Bobby Tables. Though this may look like more work with more lines, code is safer, argubaly more maintainable, and even more efficient.

Comment: Thank you Parfait!  Great answer and explanation.  I will try that.